# Best practices: Images in entries with custom HTML5-attributes

Tags: wygwam, image, metadata

I want the images in my entries look like:

> `<a data-footer="xy" data-title="xy" data-toggle="lightbox" href="img.jpg" title="xy">
>   <img class="img-responsive" alt="xy" src="/path/img.jpg" /></a>`

Right now I am using Wygwam as WYSIWYG.

I would prefer any solution where the metadata of the image is stored separately. Perhaps there is a plugin to handle this?!

I would appreciate any idea, thanks!